# Смена текста Edit при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

На форме расположена кнопка Button1Click и Edit1.Text а также и текстовый файл **1.txt** в котором есть строки:
**Например:**

```
1234567
98765432
3232323
434343434
```

Нужно что бы при нажатия на кнопку в **Edit** появилось значение первой строки **1234567**
Нажал кнопку еще появилось значение второй строки **98765432** и так далее. Но что бы по порядку.

Comment: может эти строки лучше в memo или richedit добавлять чередом? Или edit обязательно?

Comment: @sergey kuznetsov, Можно и так, что бы эти строки из Memo брать. Помогите решить вопрос.

Comment: у вас есть какие нибудь наработки события `Button1Click`?

Comment: @sergey kuznetsov, к сожалению нет. Просто не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: с pascal и delphi уже много лет не имел дел. Но я попробую по памяти написать.

Comment: @sergey kuznetsov, Благодарна тогда буду ждать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте сначала попробуем в `memo` из `.txt`. Общая логика вроде правильная, но я более, чем просто уверен, что где-то допустил ошибку, и не одну. Пробуйте этот код. И сообщайте об ошибках. Будем исправлять. Я бы на вашем месте, сначала попробовал бы позаносить значения из списка в диалог, таким способом - `ShowMessage(textFromFile.Strings[numberItem]);`, поместив данный вызов сообщения в событие клика кнопки.

Глобально описываете переменные:

```
var 
textFromFile: TStringlist;
numberItem: integer;
```

Вызываете событие инициализации формы. Тут происходит создание списка, куда заносятся значения вашего текстового файла:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
numberItem:=0;
textFromFile:=TStringlist.Create;
textFromFile.LoadFromFile('ваш_текстовый_файл.txt');
end;
```

Вызываете событие клика кнопки (вариант 1). Тут счетчик клика на кнопку, а так же создание пустой строки в memo для занесения в нее значения из созданного списка `textFromFile:=TStringlist.Create;`:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
numberItem:=numberItem+1;
//ShowMessage(textFromFile.Strings[numberItem]);
Memo1.Lines.Add;
Memo1.Lines[numberItem]:=textFromFile.Strings[numberItem];
end;
```

Вызов события клика кнопки (вариант 2):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
numberItem:=numberItem+1;
Memo1.Lines.Add;
Memo1.Lines.Insert(numberItem, textFromFile.Strings[numberItem]);
end;
```

Comment: Немного логику поняла и переделала под себя. Спасибо! Вопрос решен.

Comment: Код то работает?

Comment: Да, после некоторых правок. Просто идеально!!!!!!

Comment: @Татьяна, Боялся, что облажаюсь. Просто я на delphi сегодня начал писать спустя 8 лет, с того момента, когда в последний раз, на первом курсе вуза написал на нем последнюю лабораторную, и забыл про него :-). Ну если так, тогда я рад!

Comment: Ваш пример решил все мои задачи. Очень и очень благодарна.

Comment: Две строчки добавления строки в Memo замените на одну `Memo1.Lines.Add(textFromFile[numberItem]);`